# UnsupportedOperationException while sorting FilteredList

Tags: java, unsupportedoperation

```
private final FilteredList<ReadOnlyPerson> filteredPersons;

@Override
public void sortFilteredPersonList() {

    Comparator<ReadOnlyPerson> sortByName = new Comparator<ReadOnlyPerson>() 
{
        @Override
        public int compare(ReadOnlyPerson o1, ReadOnlyPerson o2) {
            return o1.getName().fullName.compareTo(o2.getName().fullName);
        }
    };

   filteredPersons.sort(sortByName);
}
```

I am getting unsupportedoperationexception java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:132)
May i know what is wrong with the code?

Comment: There is no indication in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/transformation/FilteredList.html that optional operations are implemented. But if they were, how would you sort the matched filtered elements around the unmatched ones?

Comment: The answers underneath [this bug-report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8103437) may help you find a workaround for your problem

Comment: It looks like FilteredLists are read-only (and it makes sense, doesn't it?)